# Adding count to query without duplicating original select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have the following code.

```
SELECT
   _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber,    _bvSerialMasterFull.SNStockLink,
   _bvSerialMasterFull.SNDateLMove,     _bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentLoc, 
   _bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentAccLink,  _bvSerialMasterFull.StockCode,
   _bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentAccount,  _bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentLocationDesc,
   _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTxDate,       _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTxReference,
   _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTrCodeID,     _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTransType,
   _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNWarehouseID,  _bvSerialNumbersFull.TransAccount,
   _bvSerialNumbersFull.TransTypeDesc,  _bvSerialNumbersFull.SerialNumber AS Expr1,
   _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNStockLink AS Expr2, _bvSerialNumbersFull.WarehouseCode,
   _bvSerialNumbersFull.TrCode,        _bvSerialNumbersFull.CurrentLocationDesc AS Expr3,
   _bvSerialNumbersFull.CurrentAccount AS Expr5, 
   WhseMst.Name, _btblInvoiceLineSN.cSerialNumber, _btblInvoiceLines.fUnitPriceExcl,
   StkItem.Code, StkItem.AveUCst, StkItem.ItemGroup
FROM _btblInvoiceLineSN INNER 
JOIN _btblInvoiceLines ON _btblInvoiceLineSN.iSerialInvoiceLineID = _btblInvoiceLines.idInvoiceLines INNER 
JOIN _bvSerialMasterFull INNER 
JOIN _bvSerialNumbersFull ON _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialCounter = _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNLink INNER
JOIN WhseMst ON _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNWarehouseID = WhseMst.WhseLink
  ON _btblInvoiceLines.iStockCodeID = _bvSerialMasterFull.SNStockLink
 AND _btblInvoiceLineSN.cSerialNumber = _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber INNER 
JOIN StkItem ON _bvSerialMasterFull.SNStockLink = StkItem.StockLink
WHERE _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTransType = 8
  AND _bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentLoc   = 1
  AND StkItem.ItemGroup IN ('010', '020', '030', '040', '050', '060', 
                            '070', '080', '100', '150', '300', '400')
ORDER BY StkItem.ItemGroup, StkItem.Code, _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTxDate
```

What this does is basically get's an inventory of certain items and does an aging analysis on them. However, the way the system works connected to this database there are some issues that need to be sorted out. This solution requires that a count on the serial number be made on the resultant dataset of this query and that count column be added in for the respective serial records.

Now the count bit is easy, and one solution I wrote is:

```
SELECT     _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber, COUNT(_bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber) AS SerialCount
FROM         _btblInvoiceLineSN INNER JOIN
                      _btblInvoiceLines ON _btblInvoiceLineSN.iSerialInvoiceLineID = _btblInvoiceLines.idInvoiceLines INNER JOIN
                      _bvSerialMasterFull INNER JOIN
                      _bvSerialNumbersFull ON _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialCounter = _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNLink INNER JOIN
                      WhseMst ON _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNWarehouseID = WhseMst.WhseLink ON 
                      _btblInvoiceLines.iStockCodeID = _bvSerialMasterFull.SNStockLink AND 
                      _btblInvoiceLineSN.cSerialNumber = _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber INNER JOIN
                      StkItem ON _bvSerialMasterFull.SNStockLink = StkItem.StockLink
WHERE     (_bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTransType = 8) AND (_bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentLoc = 1) AND (StkItem.ItemGroup IN ('010', '020', '030', '040', '050', '060', 
                      '070', '080', '100', '150', '300', '400'))
GROUP BY _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber`

Thus, using an inner join with the original query we can have:
`SELECT     Cnt.SerialCount, _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber, _bvSerialMasterFull.SNStockLink, _bvSerialMasterFull.SNDateLMove, _bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentLoc, 
                      _bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentAccLink, _bvSerialMasterFull.StockCode, _bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentAccount, _bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentLocationDesc, 
                      _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTxDate, _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTxReference, _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTrCodeID, _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTransType, 
                      _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNWarehouseID, _bvSerialNumbersFull.TransAccount, _bvSerialNumbersFull.TransTypeDesc, 
                      _bvSerialNumbersFull.SerialNumber AS Expr1, _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNStockLink AS Expr2, _bvSerialNumbersFull.WarehouseCode, 
                      _bvSerialNumbersFull.TrCode, _bvSerialNumbersFull.CurrentLocationDesc AS Expr3, _bvSerialNumbersFull.CurrentAccount AS Expr5, 
                      WhseMst.Name, _btblInvoiceLineSN.cSerialNumber, _btblInvoiceLines.fUnitPriceExcl, StkItem.Code, StkItem.AveUCst, StkItem.ItemGroup
FROM         _btblInvoiceLineSN INNER JOIN
                      _btblInvoiceLines ON _btblInvoiceLineSN.iSerialInvoiceLineID = _btblInvoiceLines.idInvoiceLines INNER JOIN
                      _bvSerialMasterFull INNER JOIN
                      _bvSerialNumbersFull ON _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialCounter = _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNLink INNER JOIN
                      WhseMst ON _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNWarehouseID = WhseMst.WhseLink ON 
                      _btblInvoiceLines.iStockCodeID = _bvSerialMasterFull.SNStockLink AND 
                      _btblInvoiceLineSN.cSerialNumber = _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber INNER JOIN
                      StkItem ON _bvSerialMasterFull.SNStockLink = StkItem.StockLink
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT     _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber, COUNT(_bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber) AS SerialCount
            FROM         _btblInvoiceLineSN INNER JOIN
                                  _btblInvoiceLines ON _btblInvoiceLineSN.iSerialInvoiceLineID = _btblInvoiceLines.idInvoiceLines INNER JOIN
                                  _bvSerialMasterFull INNER JOIN
                                  _bvSerialNumbersFull ON _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialCounter = _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNLink INNER JOIN
                                  WhseMst ON _bvSerialNumbersFull.SNWarehouseID = WhseMst.WhseLink ON 
                                  _btblInvoiceLines.iStockCodeID = _bvSerialMasterFull.SNStockLink AND 
                                  _btblInvoiceLineSN.cSerialNumber = _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber INNER JOIN
                                  StkItem ON _bvSerialMasterFull.SNStockLink = StkItem.StockLink
            WHERE     (_bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTransType = 8) AND (_bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentLoc = 1) AND (StkItem.ItemGroup IN ('010', '020', '030', '040', '050', '060', 
                                  '070', '080', '100', '150', '300', '400'))
            GROUP BY _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber
            ) Cnt ON Cnt.SerialNumber=_bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber
WHERE     (_bvSerialNumbersFull.SNTransType = 8) AND (_bvSerialMasterFull.CurrentLoc = 1) AND (StkItem.ItemGroup IN ('010', '020', '030', '040', '050', '060', 
                      '070', '080', '100', '150', '300', '400'))
```

However, as you can see, the original select query is run twice and joined together.

What I was hoping for is this to be done in the original query without the need to duplicate the original query. Can this be done? If so, your ideas, inputs and code is much appreciated.

Comment: Use a temporary table (ie name prefixed with a '#' so that it is created in *tempdb* and automatically destroyed when the connection ends) - that' what they are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using sql server 2008 or later, you can add a count to your original query like so:

```
COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY _bvSerialMasterFull.SerialNumber)
```

Doesn't need a group by.